# How to import a repo along with its Pull Requests from an existing repo

Tags: git, azure, github, repo, azure-repos

i want to import a repo which is existed in Azure DevOps project and is it possible to import that repo along with its Pull Requests history??

Answer (score 1):

As shown [in this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/449985/export-devops-repos-to-github.html), you can clone an Azure repo and [import it to GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line)

But exporting PR (pull Requests) does not seem to be natively supported (as [stated here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/591596/export-pull-request-to-pdf.html)). You would need to write a script using the [Azure PR Get Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20query/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) just to get a list, and that would not cover a full export.